# Как совершить поэлементное вычитание массивов созданных std::array

Tags: c++, массивы

Вопрос такой: Как поэлементно вычитать массивы созданные `std < array >`.

Пробовал без каста, с прямым вычитанием вида `Ae[i] - As[i]`.

Если так вообще нельзя то вопрос: как подать на вход в функцию два массива, и что то с ними там сделать? И потом ещё третий массив вернуть.
Конкретно в этой версии кода выдает `invalid static_cast from type 'std::array<int, 3>' to type 'int'`.

Если убрать `tmp`шки, и вычитать по индексам, то выдает `no match for 'operator-'(operands types are 'srd::array<int, 3>' and 'std::array<int, 3>'`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

array<int,3> gvbp(array<int,3> *As, array<int,3> *Ae)
{
    array<int,3> Ac;
    int tmp1, tmp2;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        
        tmp1 = static_cast<int>(Ae[i]);
        tmp2 = static_cast<int>(As[i]);
        Ac[i] = tmp1 - tmp2;
    }
    return Ac;
}

int main()
{
    array<int,3> *As;
    array<int,3> *Ae;
    array<int,3> Ac;
    
    array<int,3> vectorA = gvbp(As, Ae);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала массивы надо создать, так, как действуете вы — у вас указатели в никуда, типичное неопределенное поведение.

```
array<int,3> *As = new array<int,3>;
array<int,3> *Ae = new array<int,3>;
array<int,3> Ac;
....
gvbp(As, Ae);
```

Или

```
array<int,3> As;
array<int,3> Ae;
array<int,3> Ac;
....
gvbp(&As, &Ae);
```

В самой функции

```
tmp1 = static_cast<int>(Ae[i]);
tmp2 = static_cast<int>(As[i]);
```

`Ae[i]` — это `i`-й элемент переданного массива *с элементами `array`*. Как вам верно указали, нужно разыменование.

```
tmp1 = (*Ae)[i];
```

О том, что массивы у вас ничем не заполнены, я молчу.

Поскольку это C++, я бы передавал эти `array` через ссылки

```
array<int,3> gvbp(const array<int,3>& As, const array<int,3>& Ae)
{
    array<int,3> Ac;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        Ac[i] = Ae[i] - As[i];
    return Ac;
}
....
array<int,3> As{1,2,3};
array<int,3> Ae{7,8,9};
....
gvbp(As, Ae);
```

И, кстати, объявление

```
array<int,3> Ac;
```

в `main` лишнее — вы же нигде это `Ac` не используете.

Более того, для получения нужного вам результата можно воспользоваться готовым библиотечным алгоритмом:

```
array<int,3> As{1,2,3};
array<int,3> Ae{7,8,9};
array<int,3> Ac;
transform(Ae.begin(),Ae.end(),As.begin(),Ac.begin(),minus<>());
```

Все, разности записаны в `Ac`. См. https://ideone.com/qgKBuV

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

array<int,3> gvbp(array<int,3> *As, array<int,3> *Ae)
{
    array<int,3> Ac;
    int tmp1, tmp2;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        
        tmp2 = (*Ae)[i];
        tmp2 = (*As)[i];
        Ac[i] = tmp1 - tmp2;
    }
    return Ac;
}

int main()
{
    array<int,3> *As;
    array<int,3> *Ae;
    array<int,3> Ac;
    
    array<int,3> vectorA = gvbp(As, Ae);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Вы передаете в функцию указатели на массивы, а потом пытаетесь их скастовать к int... Честно говоря, моих знаний не хватает, чтобы разобраться, что у Вас получилось в результате. Но если разыменовать указатель, получив тем самым массив, а потом уже обращаться к его элементу, то вроде бы получается нормально.
Дело в том, что `std::array` ведет себя не так, как стандартный фиксированный массив с++. Подробнее почитайте, например, [здесь](https://ravesli.com/urok-94-vvedenie-v-std-array/)